# Hadoop: Ambari does not show up

Tags: hadoop

I am using VirtualBox-5.1.22 and HDP_2.6 sandbox. Installed the VirtualBox with defaults and started HDP_2.6 CenOS instance.

When I enter http://127.0.0.1:8888 I get the sandbox home page and when clicked on "Launch Dashboard", getting the following error:

[image]

I am trying in Windows 7, 64-bit OS, 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Created another instance of sandbox. It solved the problem.